# Double dimensional array value from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP file that is going to write a two-dimensional array in JavaScript:

```
<?php
    print "<script language='javascript'>";
    print " extra[0][0] = new Array(1,'Bob',12);";
    print " extra[0][1] = new Array(2,'Alice',18);";
      ..
    // Need to assign the extra[1][0], extra[1][1] and so on.
    print "</script>";
 ?>
```

#### Mu.js:

```
  var extra =  new Array();
  ...
```

How do I assign the two-dimensional array from PHP to a JavaScript variable?

Answer (score 12):

`json_encode` is your friend: [json_encode in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jsArray = <?= json_encode($my_array) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: I have encoded in PHP, I unable to decode in javascript ,could u please suggest an example?

Comment: Just build the array in PHP as you want it to look in Javascript, and then pass that array to json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, wvanbergen is right, json_encode is your friend. You can create the array as JSON:

```
<?php
    $extra = array(
      array(1,'Bob',12),
      array(2,'Alice',18)
      );

    echo "var extra = " . json_encode($extra) . ";";
?>
```

And in your javascript it will output:

```
var extra = [[1,"Bob",12],[2,"Alice",18]];
```

Answer (score -5):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var jsArray = <?php json_encode($my_array); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: In your code it will only encode the array, but won't display it.